# Sending a Request with JSON and Getting Back JSON iOS8

Tags: ios, json, get, request

I have to send a JSON - with device id and type - to API, and it will give me another JSON with token and few other things.

I'm fairly new to iOS, it has been three weeks and I'm really new to web services. So, I couldn't figure out how to both send and get a JSON.

I'm trying to use AFNetworking at the same time, which is in my opinion the simplest way. So, I thought it might be good to use POST to send a JSON and I achieved with the following code:

```
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];//DeviceID
    NSLog(@"unique idf: %@ and type: %@", uniqueIdentifier, [[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] stringValue]);

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"DeviceId" : uniqueIdentifier, @"Type" : [[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] stringValue]};

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];


[manager GET:BaseURLString parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

So, it returns me the device id and type, I know from writing to log. However I stuckted there. On the other hand, it doesn't reach to the success block. I debuged it right now, and also no printing on log screen although there was a command NSLog for it. What might be problem?

It's just confusing to construct a GET there, for me, honestly. So, I would be really appreciated if you can help me to figure out that situation.

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of data is `responseObject`?

Comment: You send json and it gives you json - how does that work ?

Comment: why you want to write GET method in success block, what it will give?

Comment: The answers are, respectively: 1) responseObject should be JSON right? Because I send a request and the API's return will be JSON to me. 2) It works like, I send request with json, it gives me another json in respond to it. 3) Doesn't GET method give me the respond coming from API? I am not clear there. It might be change.

Comment: GET should be used for requests where you are requesting some data from the specified resource. Note that the query string (name/value pairs) is sent in the URL of a GET request: as a parameters. check if you sending the correct parameters with GET requests and referring to the correct URL.

Comment: Hmm. I think I'm coming on to your way. So you suggest me to use GET instead of POST, right? I edited the code, and also added an issue to the paragraph below. I just realized that it doesn't reach success block.

Comment: You need to check the server API doc or talk to the server guy who has the information about which (GET or POST) should be send from the client.

Comment: Okay, I will. Before it, just for clearification, here is a quick question. Please help me about it. With using GET method, doesn't I tell to API to take that parameters (in the method) and give me the respond. - Please find the last edited version, since I used request type this time.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your success block do this -

`[self performSelector:@selector(makeGetRequest:) withObject:responseObject];`

Write the GET functionality in "makeGetRequest" method

`-(void)makeGetRequest:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"responseObject - %@",sender);
    // Write GET functionality here
}`

Comment: And what about that GET functionality? Should it be the GET method of AFNetworking ?

Comment: Yes, you need to write the get method. Example - 
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:@"https://example.com" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // do whatever you'd like here; for example, if you want to convert 
    // it to a string and log it, you might do something like:

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];